# Function that copies last value for each second until next datapoint in Python 2.7, piecewise constant interpolation

Tags: python, python-2.7, time-series, interpolation

I'm working in Python 2.7, and I've got timestamps and corresponding values. I want to set these values to a time base of one value for each second, namely, the last measured value. So:

```
[[1,  4,  6],
 [15, 17, 12]]
```

to:

```
[[1,  2,  3,  4,  4,  6],
 [15, 15, 15, 17, 17, 12]]
```

I've come up with this, which does what I want, but there must a more elegant way. Does anyone know of one?

```
import numpy as np

#Example data:
origdata= {}
origdata['time'] = [4, 26, 37, 51, 59, 71, 93]
origdata['vals'] = [17, 5, 43, 21, 14, 8, np.NaN]

extratime = [t-1 for t in origdata['time']]
data={}
data['time'] = np.concatenate((origdata['time'][:-1], extratime[1:]), axis=0)
data['vals'] = np.concatenate((origdata['vals'][:-1], origdata['vals'][:-1]), axis=0)

sorter = data['time'].argsort()
data['time'] = data['time'][sorter]
data['vals'] = data['vals'][sorter]

filledOutData = {}
filledOutData['time'] = range(data['time'][0], data['time'][-1])
filledOutData['vals'] = np.interp(filledOutData['time'], data['time'], data['vals'])
```

Plotting the original data and desired result with the following code gives the image below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(origdata['time'], origdata['vals'], '-o', filledOutData['time'], filledOutData['vals'], '.-')
plt.legend(['original', 'desired result'])
plt.show
```

[image: An illustration of what I want]

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a truncate option to do this automatically, I will look into it

Comment: Might have found it, `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` with `kind='zero'` looks promising

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is called piecewise constant interpolation which can be done with the scipy package:

```
import scipy as sp

interpolator = sp.interpolate.interp1d(origdata['time'], origdata['vals'], kind='zero')

filledOutData2 = {}
filledOutData2['time'] = range(origdata['time'][0],origdata['time'][-1])
filledOutData2['vals'] = interpolator(filledOutData2['time'])
```

Edit:
Or as a function:

```
def interp_piecewise_constant(times,values):
  interpolator = sp.interpolate.interp1d(times, values, kind='zero')
  newTimes = range(times[0], times[-1])
  return(newTimes, interpolator(newTimes))
```

Comment: that is a good answer - i dont use numpy or scipy so wouldn't know it but for the question its a very sound thing to do ;}

Comment: are you not just using the comment made by the asker a few minutes ago?

Comment: Yeah, it was pretty easy to implement once I finally found it so I could answer my own question

Comment: lol, I got confused as to who was asking/answering and thought this was someone else stealing the solution you suggested in comment.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
data = {}
times = [4, 26, 37, 51, 59, 71, 93]
vals = [17, 5, 43, 21, 14, 8, float('nan')]
# i don't have numpy so i had to change to nan

for i in range(times[0], times[-1]+1):
    if i in times:
        v = vals[times.index(i)]
    data.setdefault('time', []).append(i)
    data.setdefault('vals', []).append(v)

print data['time']
```

[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93]

```
print data['vals']
```

[17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, nan]

Comment: this is both horribly inefficient and does not accomplish the task in a more elegant way which was the original question.

Comment: in your opinion - but it is shorter and doesn't require sorting so i am afraid you are overstating its inefficiency

Comment: oh I'm sorry I misunderstood how the original code was working, still you really don't need the `setdefault` in the for loop since you can just initialize data with the actual lists in it

Comment: true - but the setdefault to my understanding doesn't really add a lot of overhead and it allows you to not add an initial key - but the whole thing is moot since the scipy answer is probably better anyway :}

Comment: no the actual running of `setdefault` doesn't add much but getting the `setdefault` method on the `dict`, creating a bunch of new lists, deleting the lists because they are never used and getting the `append` method are all adding a lot of time, like 2.5X my test that keeps a reference to the `.append` of both lists. (used timeit)

Comment: although my suggested solution run 4X faster then that, still I completely take back what I said about this not being elegant, this is a great way to do it. (other then `setdefault`)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a generator to create the in-between data values:

```
def piecewise(x_vals,y_vals,offset=0.1):
    iter_x = iter(x_vals)
    iter_y = iter(y_vals) #use iterators
    y = next(iter_y)#get first y value
    yield next(iter_x),y #first pair
    while True:
        x = next(iter_x)
        yield x-offset, y #gives the x value - offset with previous y value
        y = next(iter_y)
        yield x,y        #actual data points
```

basically for lists of [x1,x2,x3...] and [y1,y2,y3...] this generates the output:

```
(x1,y1), (x2-1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3-1,y2), (x3,y3)...
```

So it only creates twice the amount of original data points instead of all the other solutions that create all the possible in between points with integers. (this would work just as well with small decimal values)

this way you can create the filled in data like this:

```
filledOutData= {'time':[],'vals':[]}
for x,y in piecewise(origdata['time'],origdata['vals']):
    filledOutData['time'].append(x)
    filledOutData['vals'].append(y)
```

or shorter with `zip` and simultaneous assignment:

```
filledOutData= {}
filledOutData['time'],filledOutData['vals'] = zip(*piecewise(origdata['time'],origdata['vals']))
```

[image: diagram of output]

note that this probably only works if the original time list is sorted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What about a generator?

```
>>> def fill(times, vals):
...     lt, lv = times[0], vals[0]
...     for nt, nv in zip(times[1:], vals[1:]):
...         while lt < nt:
...             yield lt, lv
...             lt += 1
...         lt, lv = nt, nv
...     yield nt, nv
...
>>> times = [4, 26, 37, 51, 59, 71, 93]
... vals = [17, 5, 43, 21, 14, 8, float('nan')]
...
>>> list(fill(times, vals))
[(4, 17),
(5, 17),
(6, 17),
...
(91, 8),
(92, 8),
(93, nan)]
```

If you need separate lists, you can unzip the generated tuples in this way:

```
>>> from itertools import tee
>>> filled_times, filled_vals = [list((t[idx] for t in it)) 
...                              for idx, it in enumerate(tee(fill(times, vals)))]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should time great and has a pretty simple logic structure.

```
def interpolate(data):
    times, values = data
    output = []

    time, end, index = times[0], times[-1], 0
    while time <= end:
        if time == times[index + 1]:
            index += 1
        output.append((time, values[index]))
        time += 1

    return zip(*output)

print interpolate([[1, 4, 6], [15, 17, 12]])
# [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), (15, 15, 15, 17, 17, 12)]
```